# Fusion table ST_INTERSECTS not work

Tags: google-fusion-tables

My App using fusiontable to select records id by ST_INTERSECTS working fine before suddenly not work now!

```
var queryText = encodeURIComponent("select id from "+ v_TableID +" where ST_INTERSECTS(address, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + lat + ',' + lng + '),' + 1000 + '))' + "and" + v_select + "and id > 1" );
var query = new google.visualization.Query("http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=" + queryText);
```

If removed `ST_INTERSECTS(address, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + lat + ',' + lng + '),' + 1000 + '))`it work fine

```
var queryText = encodeURIComponent("select id from "+ v_TableID +" where " + v_select + "and id > 1");
var query = new google.visualization.Query("http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=" + queryText);
```

if i modify fusion table address(eg: 22.2202,113.9196 change to 22.22,113.919) it work again but only the first time.

**Additional information**

> var v_select = 'category in ("abc","xyz")';

i try again than find out

```
var queryText = encodeURIComponent("select id from "+ v_TableID +" where ST_INTERSECTS(address, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + lat + ',' + lng + '),' + 1000 + '))' + "and" + 'category in ("abc","xyz")' + "and id > 1" );
var query = new google.visualization.Query("http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=" + queryText);
```

if i remove "category in ("abc","xyz")" OR "ST_INTERSECTS(address, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + lat + ',' + lng + ')" work fine.

Is it not allow to use "in" and "ST_INTERSECTS" together now?

Before 28/10/2012 it work fine i use the same clause already 6 months but now not work.

Please help

Comment: Do you have an example map or a jsfiddle that shows the problem?  [This example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_circle_geocode_gviz.html) seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that this isn't an answer (I don't have enough rep to make a comment) but it might help in solving this problem - I am having a similar problem with an almost identical query which has worked for a while. It seems to be because of the switch from Numeric tableID's to encrypted tableID's - that's the only difference in my two versions of code. Is the poster using encrypted table ID's? Working to try and fix this with no luck so far...